# FusionAuth dashboard login failure - InvalidReferenceException / missing loginData

Tags: freemarker, fusionauth

I'm working with what I believe is a fairly standard FusionAuth installation. From a few days ago, admin users have been unable to access the Dashboard at [myhost]:[myport]/admin/ (aside from this, FusionAuth appears to be working as normal).

Once a user has entered their login credentials, the page becomes unresponsive for some time (typically several minutes), before presenting them with this (obviously generic) message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fimQv.png)

The StdErr logs show the following:
*Jun 08, 2020 3:05:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
org.primeframework.mvc.freemarker.FreeMarkerRenderException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> loginData  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 46]*

The relevant section of index.ftl is as follows:

```
[@layout.html]
[@layout.head]
  <script>
    Prime.Document.onReady(function() {
      new FusionAuth.Admin.Dashboard([[#list loginData.labels as label]"${label}"[#sep], [/#list]],
          [[#list loginData.counts as count]${count}[#sep], [/#list]]);
    });
  </script>
[/@layout.head]
```

...and the loginData variable is declared as follows:
`[#-- @ftlvariable name="loginData" type="io.fusionauth.app.service.ReportUtil.ReportData" --]`

If a user enters the wrong password, they get the usual failure message, with little delay; this issue seems to occur after initial authentication. I understand that loginData is likely to be a report, but am uncertain of its significance (and the standard FusionAuth login report seems to work OK when I call the API via Postman). Has anyone had a similar issue?

Edit: I'm advised that this is a standard installation, with Elasticsearch and MySQL as recommended. User count isn't believed to be unusual (totals report gives globalRegistrations and totalGlobalRegistrations in the 7500 to 8500 range).

Additional information:

Versions:

- OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard, V1809
- MySql: 8.0
- ElasticSearch:6.3.1
- FusionAuth: 1.9.1

There have been no known recent deliberate changes to this FusionAuth system

When the error occurs, no error were initially reported in the JS Console, but I've now seen one relating to a missing "]", and the reason for this is that the error message seen below appears to have been inserted into the page source, presumably while it was being generated using a template:

```
  <script>
    var FusionAuth = FusionAuth || {};
    FusionAuth.requestContextPath = '';
    FusionAuth.loginURI = FusionAuth.requestContextPath + '/login';
  </script>

  <script>
    Prime.Document.onReady(function() {
      new FusionAuth.Admin.Dashboard([FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!):
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> loginData  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 46]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use [#if myOptionalVar??]when-present[#else]when-missing[/#if]. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list loginData.labels as label  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 39]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "head" at line 124, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.head  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 20, column 1]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "html" at line 14, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.html  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 19, column 1]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:85)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.<init>(UnexpectedTypeException.java:48)
    at freemarker.core.NonHashException.<init>(NonHashException.java:49)

...
```

**Possible cause: I do see some apparent MySQL timeouts, now that I come to check the StdOut logs rather than StdErr; maybe that's the issue; will confirm** - scratch that; the latest case was not accompanied by any obvious MySQL-related log entries.

Latest full error message (some lines removed from stack trace to save space. This error was not preceded directly by anything in either the StdOut or StdErr logs; it was the day's first entry in the StdErr log):

```
Jun 11, 2020 9:55:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
org.primeframework.mvc.freemarker.FreeMarkerRenderException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> loginData  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 46]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use [#if myOptionalVar??]when-present[#else]when-missing[/#if]. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list loginData.labels as label  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 39]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "head" at line 124, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.head  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 20, column 1]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "html" at line 14, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.html  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 19, column 1]
----
    at org.primeframework.mvc.freemarker.DefaultFreeMarkerService.render(DefaultFreeMarkerService.java:69)
    ...
    at io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.FusionAuthMVCWorkflow.perform(FusionAuthMVCWorkflow.java:93)
    ...
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> loginData  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 46]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use [#if myOptionalVar??]when-present[#else]when-missing[/#if]. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #list loginData.labels as label  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 23, column 39]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "head" at line 124, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.head  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 20, column 1]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/_layouts/admin.ftl" in macro "html" at line 14, column 3]
    ~ Reached through: @layout.html  [in template "WEB-INF/templates/admin/index.ftl" at line 19, column 1]
----
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134)
    ...
    at org.primeframework.mvc.freemarker.DefaultFreeMarkerService.render(DefaultFreeMarkerService.java:65)
    ... 35 more
```

**Work-around:** If we go to, for example, [host:port]/admin/user (ie. specify a page other than the Dashboard), the actual admin functionality can be used as normal.

**NB** A similar issue occurs if we attempt to use [host:port]admin/system/login-record/ 
**Possible query issue**
We have  notices that the following query - which is believed to be the one that pulls the login data involved in this issue - is running slowly and locking up database connections:

```
SELECT
    rl.applications_id            AS applicationId,
    rl.instant                    AS instant,
    rl.ip_address                 AS ipAddress,
    rl.users_id                   AS userId,
    a.name                        AS applicationName,
    COALESCE(i.email, i.username) AS loginId
    FROM raw_logins AS rl
    INNER JOIN applications AS a ON a.id = rl.applications_id
    INNER JOIN identities AS i ON i.users_id = rl.users_id

    ORDER BY rl.instant DESC
    LIMIT 5
    OFFSET 0
```

Is this a standard FusionAuth query? Have performance issues been reported with it?

Comment: Is there anything unique about your installation? User count, Elasticsearch or database search?

Comment: @robotdan Thanks for the quick response. I don't believe there's anything unique about this installation (have edited the question description)

Comment: @roger can you please provide more details?

* how did you install this

* versions of OS, mysql, elasticsearch, fusionauth

* log lines just before the error message

* any recent changes to the system (did you upgrade?)

* any error messages in the javascript console

* does this affect all admin users or just certain ones? If the latter, any differences between the accounts that work and those which do not?

Ack, sorry for the formatting!

Comment: @mooreds I'll find out (I didn't do this installation personally; apologies for the vagueness)
As for admin users, it appears to affect them all (we only had one, but I created another from scratch via the REST API, and it was similarly affected)

Comment: @mooreds I've updated the issue description. I initially wasn't aware of anything in the console, but further reproduction does show an error there; please see description

Comment: @roger thanks for the additional detail. I wasn't able to find any other folks with issues with this query. It's not immediately obvious to me what the issue is, but I'm glad you found the workaround. At this point, I think you have these options:

1. upgrade to a later version of fusionauth and see if this was fixed. You can read the release notes for bugfix details.
2. file a github bug report. FA 1.9.1 is pretty old, but maybe this is still an issue in the current codebase
3. buy support to access to engineering support (or open a ticket if you already have it)
4. use the workaround

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better suggestion!